# Export function from mathematica to matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface, wolfram-mathematica, linear-algebra

Im trying to export a function that draws a heart from mathematica...

```
Export[NotebookDirectory[] <> "anim1.gif", Table[
   Plot[Sqrt[Cos[x]]*Cos[200*x] + Sqrt[Abs[x]] - 0.7*(4 - x*x)^0.01,
   {x, -2, t}, PlotStyle -> Red, Frame -> True,
   Axes -> False, PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-1.7, 1.1}}]
, {t, -1.57, 2, 0.01}]]
```

[image]

...to matlab.
But I dont know how instead of making a gif a would like to draw the image in a single step, to apply some processes later over the image.

I have trying to make a symbolic variable with

```
>> sim x
```

But when entering the function that try to plot

```
plot([Sqrt[Cos[x]]*Cos[200*x] + Sqrt[Abs[x]] - 0.7*(4 - x*x)^0.01,))
```

it always says.

```
Error: Unbalanced or unexpected parenthesis or bracket.
```

**Update**
I have managed to plot it as

```
x = [-2:0.000001:2];
>> plot ((sqrt(cos(x).*cos(200*x))+sqrt(abs(x)))-(0.7*(4-x.^2).^(0.01)))
```

But still gives me the next incomplete image

[image]

Comment: And what is the function line in MATLAB that gives the error? You don’t expect the Mathematica code to run in MATLAB, are you?

Comment: MATLAB doesn’t use square brackets in this way. I recommend that you start by taking one of the introductory tutorials first. https://matlabacademy.mathworks.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining  a time vector

```
x=[-2:.001:2];
```

Writing the function

```
 y=(sqrt(cos(x)).*cos(200*x)+sqrt(abs(x))-0.7).*(4-x.*x).^0.01;
```

ploting it

```
 plot(x,y)

Warning: Imaginary parts of complex X and/or Y arguments ignored
```

[image]